# Centos shell script - Group files starting with the same string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ls

I have a directory with many pdf files. Each file name starts with a numeric ID (5 chars fixed length), as follows:

```
11111-2014.pdf  
11111-2015.pdf  
22222-2015.pdf  
33333-2013.pdf  
33333-2014.pdf  
33333-2015.pdf
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write a shell script in CentOS that reads files in such directory and list them depending on the ID.
The shell script should return the following output (on 3 rows) as following:

```
11111-2014.pdf 11111-2015.pdf  
22222-2015.pdf  
33333-2013.pdf 33333-2014.pdf 33333-2015.pdf
```

and assign to each row a variable name (ie: $rowstring).

I would like to group in a string all the files starting with the same ID, and attach them to the same email using mutt email client by command line. So, following the above example:

for each unique $rowstring the command would be:

```
mutt -s "subject" $rowstring -- abc@domain.com < body.txt
```

where $rowstring (the attachments) should look like as follows
For the first email:

```
-a 11111-2014.pdf -a 11111-2015.pdf
```

For the second email:

```
-a 22222-2014.pdf
```

For the third email:

```
-a 33333-2013.pdf -a 33333-2014.pdf -a 33333-2015.pdf
```

I tried to combine ls and awk commands but I'm too newbie to succeed.
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command:

```
 ls  | awk -F '-' 'BEGIN{temp=""} temp&&$1!=temp{printf "\n"} {printf "-a %s ",$0; temp = $1}'
```

outputs:

```
-a 11111-2014.pdf -a 11111-2015.pdf
-a 22222-2015.pdf
-a 33333-2013.pdf -a 33333-2014.pdf -a 33333-2015.pdf
```

You can then use each line one at a time and send mail.

Comment: Great answer, thanks you! Do you know a way to assign a variable name to each row? My idea was: for each unique pdf ID found (ie 11111), run your suggested command in order to return the row with all the pdf files which start with 11111, and assign a variable name to that row (so, I could use it elsewhere). Thank you.